# How does salesforce generate a unique URL for each org and registers it on their domain provider dynamically?

Tags: sandbox, url

So every time we create an org a unique URL is generated for the org, I'm very curious as to how it is working from a domain point of view. Do they create the subdomain URL while creating an org and then register it simultaneously?
I thought they might be using wild card subdomains but that is not how it works.

For example, on go daddy I have had to create a wild card subdomain so that I can create URLs on run time for the users which they would use to access the site. but all other *.myDomain.com also land on my site. salesforce somehow bypasses this and only allows the URLs which it creates.

Answer (score 0):

Domain names are resolved by DNS servers. This is a nested hierarchy, where each domain can further control subdomains by using DNS NS records. In salesforce.com, we'll find the following NS entries (at time of this answer):

- pch1.salesforce-dns.com
- pch2.salesforce-dns.com
- udns1.salesforce.com
- udns2.salesforce.com
- udns3.salesforce.com
- udns4.salesforce.com

So, in general, the `.com` TLD has an entry for `salesforce.com`, and that DNS entry has values to resolve subdomains, using one of the six servers above. When creating an org, it simply has to create a CNAME entry for that subdomain on these six servers (alongside the other various domains they have, like force.com).

A wildcard domain is literally an entry like `*.example.com`, and it will be referenced for any non-existent domains. If a domain doesn't have this wildcard domain, then all invalid subdomains will be met with "unable to locate IP address" errors.

The requirement for GoDaddy to require a wildcard domain is something they specifically chose to enforce. There Internet itself doesn't need a wildcard domain; if one is not provided, it simply provides "no result". DNS servers get to choose the rules they play by, as long as they are compatible with [RFC 1034](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034), [RFC 1035](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035), and all further RFCs that update these RFCs.